# Weird characters appear in Vbulletin after moving servers. ( don't appears as donâ€™t )

Tags: vbulletin

After moving vbulletin to another server some characters like " ' got converted to characters like â€ for example: don't appears as donâ€™t

New posts don't seem to use these weird characters.

Can you recommend what way can I take to replace these weird characters with the correct ones?  I.e Should I write a SQL query ?

Here is a sample thread:

http://www.fixxi.net/community/threads/670-Fixxi-NSP-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D-The-Voices%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D-movie-review?p=915#post915

The MySQL database is running collation utf8_general_ci. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your new server is sending back a Content-Type header that gives the charset as **ISO-8859-1**, here's a sample response:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:13693
Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 14 Aug 2015 17:49:07 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:private
Server:Apache
```

If you have access to the Apache configuration, take a look for `AddDefaultCharset` - you want it to be something like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

What Tim Fountain said is correct.  Alternatively, you can replace the characters in your existing data.  Depending on what your allowed characters were at the time of data entry, the issue is often limited to double and single curly quotes, and hyphens.  As those are commonly allowed in text entry fields and differ between UTF-8 and 8859.